# Negative Rule for EJB WS

Tags: java, web-services, .htaccess, ejb

I have a RewriteMatch on my apache virutal host as follow

```
ServerName domain
RewriteMatch ^/$ /context
```

the ear also has a ejb based service served from `http://domain/servicepath/Service?wsdl`

I would like to **add** a negative rule so any uri that is not ^/$ goes directly to the ROOT context like

```
http://domain/servicepath/Service?wsdl
```

and all /context keep going thryu /context anyway

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use this regex:

```
RewriteMatch ^/$ /context

RewriteMatch ^/(?!context).+$ http://domain/servicepath/Service?wsdl
```

Comment: kepping the old one and having both right? I mean, to keep the / redirect and add the negative rule

Comment: sorry, but what about /context? it should keep going thru http : //domain/context